# Is Naradha Muni a Mischief Maker as Depicted in popular culture

Tags: vishnu, bhakti, narada

Few South Indian movies portray Naradha muni as mischief maker involving in creation of quarrels between Wives of Trimurti (Lord Shiva, Lord Brahma & Lord MahaVishnu). He also involves in creating fights between Deva's and the Asura's.

Vaishnavas describe him as an elevated soul devoted to Narayana bhakthi.

Are there any credible sources to portray him as a trouble maker?

Answer (score 7):

nAram dadAti iti nAradah. He who gives knowledge is nArada. nArada muni is a guru swarUpa and should be revered by all. You will remember all the various instances in which the sage was instrumental in the birth and propagation of knowledge in this earthly realm. To name a few:-

1. His teaching to Valmiki resulted in the Ramayana
2. His teaching to Vyasa resulted in the bhAgavata which is verily a mOksha kAvya.
3. His teaching to sumEdha resulted in the tripurA rahasya which is another work on Atma vidya.
4. There is also a very recent account of his imparting nAda yoga to Tyagaraja by way of the treatise- swarArNava.

His depiction in movies as a trouble-maker is incorrect and deplorable.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: Nice answer, he also gave the Narada Bhakti Sutra :)

Answer (score 3):

Getting ideas about Gods, saints, religious and allied stuffs by watching movies is the last thing you should do I guess.

Anyways, Devarishi Narad is not the trouble maker as he often appears to be.

His moves are always sanctioned by the Lord himself and his actions play key role in fructifying God's plan of action or loosely speaking, he triggers things that were to happen in future by his so called mischievous moves.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan At present i'm not able to cite any sources.So,if you can and wish,please convert my answer into a comment.I may again post it  as an answer if i find appropriate sources.